# Unable to cast object to of type 'system.argumentexception' to type 'system.windows.forms.iwin32window'

Tags: vb.net, winforms, datagridview, .net-4.0

I have a datagridview which is bound to a datasource. I was trying to replace DGV's 1st column with `datagridviewcomboboxcolumn`, but it gives me the following exception:

> Unable to cast object to of type 'system.argumentexception' to type 'system.windows.forms.iwin32window'

Here's my code.

```vb
Public Sub formdata()
    Try

        Dim query As String = "select th.catalogue,th.name,pi.itemcode,th.itemcode,pi.party_code " _
        & "from partyitem pi,itemhead th where th.itemcode=pi.itemcode and pi.party_code=" & valpartycode & " order by th.catalogue"

        adap = New OleDbDataAdapter(query, conn)
        ds = New DataSet
        ds.Clear()
        adap.Fill(ds, "partyitem")
        DataGridView1.DataSource = ds.Tables(0)

        DataGridView1.Columns.Item(0).HeaderText = "CATALOGUE"
        DataGridView1.Columns.Item(0).Width = 180
        DataGridView1.Columns.Item(1).HeaderText = "NAME"
        DataGridView1.Columns.Item(1).Width = 350
        DataGridView1.Columns.Item(2).Visible = False
        DataGridView1.Columns.Item(3).Visible = False
        DataGridView1.Columns.Item(4).Visible = False

        Dim query1 As String = "select catalogue from itemhead where itemcode not in" _
                       & "(select itemcode from partyitem where party_code=" & valpartycode & ") order by catalogue"

        adapnew = New OleDbDataAdapter(query1, conn)
        Dim ds1 As New DataSet
        adapnew.Fill(ds1, "itemhead")

        Me.DataGridView1.Columns.Remove("catalogue")
        Dim datacol As New DataGridViewComboBoxColumn
        With datacol
            .Name = "catalogue"
            .DataPropertyName = "catalogue"
            .DataSource = ds1.Tables(0)
            .ValueMember = "catalogue"
            .DisplayMember = "catalogue"
            .HeaderText = "CATALOGUE"
            .FlatStyle = FlatStyle.Flat
            .DropDownWidth = 160
            .Width = 200
        End With
        Me.DataGridView1.Columns.Insert(0, datacol)

    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Message", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error)
    End Try
End Sub
```

I did the same for this below datagridview in another form, it is working fine and here's that code.

```vb
Public Sub formdata()
    Try
        Dim query As String = "SELECT Itemcategory.categoryname," _
                              & "PartyDiscount.discount,PartyDiscount.cash_discount,PartyDiscount.turnover_discount" _
                                & " from Itemcategory,PartyDiscount where PartyDiscount.category=Itemcategory.categorycode" _
                                & " and PartyDiscount.party_code=" & valpartycode & " order by itemcategory.categoryname"

        adap = New OleDbDataAdapter(query, conn)
        ds = New DataSet
        ds.Clear()
        adap.Fill(ds, "partydiscount")
        DataGridView1.DataSource = ds.Tables(0)

        DataGridView1.Columns.Item(0).HeaderText = "PRODUCT GROUP"
        'DataGridView1.Columns.Item(0).Width = 170
        DataGridView1.Columns.Item(1).HeaderText = "DISCOUNT"
        DataGridView1.Columns.Item(1).Width = 90
        DataGridView1.Columns.Item(2).HeaderText = "CASH DISCOUNT"
        DataGridView1.Columns.Item(2).Width = 90
        DataGridView1.Columns.Item(3).HeaderText = "TURNOVER DISCOUNT"
        DataGridView1.Columns.Item(3).Width = 95

        adapnew = New OleDbDataAdapter("Select categoryname from itemcategory where itemtype='F' order by categoryname", conn)
        Dim dsnew As New DataSet
        adapnew.Fill(dsnew, "itemcategory")

        Me.DataGridView1.Columns.Remove("categoryname")
        Dim datacol As New DataGridViewComboBoxColumn
        With datacol
            .Name = "categoryname"
            .DataPropertyName = "categoryname"
            .DataSource = dsnew.Tables(0)
            .ValueMember = "categoryname"
            .DisplayMember = "categoryname"
            .HeaderText = "PRODUCT GROUP"
            .FlatStyle = FlatStyle.Flat
            .DropDownWidth = 160
            .Width = 200
        End With
        Me.DataGridView1.Columns.Insert(0, datacol)

    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Message", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error)
    End Try
End Sub
```

Don't know why the above code is going wrong. Please help me out.

**Edit:**

stacktrace:

> at MYsoft.PMitemlist.datagridview1_dataerror(Object sender,datagridviewdataerroreventargs e) in
>   E:\Harry\Mysoft\MYSOFT\PMitemlist.vb:list 226

**Edit 2:**

```vb
Try
    Dim a As Exception = e.Exception
Catch ex As Exception
    MessageBox.Show(ex.StackTrace.ToString, "Message", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error)
End Try
```

It also give the following exception

> system.argumentexception :datagridviewcomboboxcell value is not valid

Comment: That's weird. Could you post the stacktrace to better understand where the exception occurs?

Comment: that's the stacktrace.

Comment: initially it showed me an exception:system.argumentexecption: datagridviewcomboboxcell value is not valid.

Comment: This error seems to be raised in a differen place. Do you have code in the event datagridview1_DataError ?? What is that code?

Comment: Sorry, but can't understand well code in comments. Could you add that to the original question?

Comment: Don't use string concatenation to substitute your `valpartycode` into the sql queries! That technique leaves you crazy-vulnerable to sql injection attacks. Learn to use query parameters.